# Halachot of standing in a supermarket line

Tags: halacha, money, transactions

Looking for a Shu"T that covers the following issues of standing in a supermarket line (*assuming there are no Dina DM laws covering that*):

- Is standing in a line a sort of Kinyan? Is it a monetary issue and Can it be sold or inherited (*like a 4 days line for a new Ipone*) or given out as a gift?
- Can one refill his cart while keeping his place in a line? Does it depend if the majority of the cart is already filled or not? Can one put his empty cart in a line at the beginning and keep filling it later?
- Can one use his relatives/friends to keep his place in the line while he shops around?
- If a new cashier opens, who has the precedence - those who are the closest to him or those who stood the longest?
- Can one hold two places in two or more lines simultaneously?
- Can one decide to let another customer pass before him (like one that has a few items only)?

---

<sub>NB: Do Jews and Non-Jews have similar HALACHIC (not-civil) rights of standing in the line or should they be more stringent/lenient (*we have this problem with the Arabs in Jerusalem's biggest supermarkets - גזל, דרכי שלום*)? In other words, should a Jew behave in a more stringent/lenient way with them?</sub>

Comment: interesting question. Related - if you get a number and you do not appear at the window when your number is called, and you later return, do you lose your place permanently, or do you automatically go next on line ahead of someone with a later number than you?

Comment: R Chaim Kanievski was asked your second question. He answered "maybe". Must be a strong question then ;-> (glad I +1'd when it came out) See https://www.tabletmag.com/jewish-arts-and-culture/270668/hayim-kanievsky-instant-responsa (search for "spot in line")